# Async function with one try catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
async function handlePersonalInformation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = initialInfo(data);
    try {
      await getPersonalInfo();
      try {
        await updatePersonalInfo(formData);
        alert('Successfully updated!');
      } catch (error) {
        handleError(error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      try {
        await createPersonalInfo(data);
        alert('Your personal infromation has been saved');
      } catch (error) {
        handleError(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to refactor this function using only one try / catch block.
Unfortunately without success.

Comment: it seems you need a way to find out if personal information is created before using the getPersonalInfo(), if you can only find out there's no info through an error, then I don't see a way to reduce this to a single try catch

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this code is that exception thrown by `getPersonalInfo` is treated as a normal business case: you always go with 'create...' fork if there's an error. Yet I don't think that's the correct implementation: what if that request failed because of some other reason, different from 404?

The better approach seems to be isolating this function, making it only throw real errors:

```
function wrappedGetPersonalInfo(data) {
  try {
    const res = await getPersonalInfo(data);
    return res;
  } catch (e) { // I wish there were typed catches
    if (e instanceof NotFoundError) { // the check should suit your case
      return null;
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

... then you'll be able to streamline your code quite a lot:

```
try {
  const res = await wrappedGetPersonalInfo(data);
  if (res) {
    await updatePersonalInfo(formData);
    alert('Successfully updated!');
  }
  else {
    await createPersonalInfo(data);
    alert('Your personal infromation has been saved');
  }
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

Comment: In my case, it is throwing only error 404 Page not found. So should I have this e instance of ... to return null and then to throw an error? What should be the instance of the error for Page not found 404 is there any generic error for that? Because I do not have any idea how to create a custom error for that. As well I do not know, what kind of other error I could have except that ... looks like it is throwing only 404.

Comment: Well, there's always timeouts at least (which you can easily simulate), so no, 404 is not the only thing that throws. As for exact type of error, you can either check the documentation for the library you use under - or log the error itself and adapt to the uncovered details.